# Underline text in Xamarin with a styled underline

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to underline text like so:
[Text with a styled underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlakP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overlap the label above a box view to get the desired result.

```
    <Grid>
            <BoxView
                HeightRequest="6"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference label}, Path=Width}" Color="Gold" VerticalOptions="End"/>
            <Label
                x:Name="label"
                FontSize="30"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Text="The Steps">
            </Label>
        </Grid>
```

**Result view screen shot**

[image: result UI]

But if the space around `p` lower stroke at the underline gap could not be achieved. If the space is necessary try using [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/) (A drawing library).

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Forms provide TextDecorations property.Please Try below code

```
 <StackLayout
        Padding="30"
        BackgroundColor="#fafafa"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label
            FontSize="Large"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Text="The Steps"
            TextDecorations="Underline" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: will this allow me to make the underline a different thickness and colour?

Comment: @Connor No this allow you make only underline. If you want thickness and different color then you need to create custom renderer

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/xamarinforms-custom-underline-label